# How do you retrieve data from your firebase realtime database to selectable HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, html-table

I am trying to retrieve data from my firebase realtime database, and then append them onto my HTML table. However, I don't have any ideas on how to create the HTML table that is selectable and submit what I selected. Here is how my database tree looks like.

[image]

Here is the HTML table I made.

```
<table class="hotel-list" id="Marriott-hotel-list">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
        <th>Hotel Name</th>
        <th>Hotel Location</th>
        <th>Cheap Room's Price</th>
        <th>Amount of Cheap Room</th>
        <th>Expensive Room's Price</th>
        <th>Amount of Cheap Room</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr">
        <td id="Hotel-Name"></td>
        <td id="Hotel-location"></td>
        <td id="Cheap-Rooms-Price"></td>
        <td id="Amount-of-Cheap-Room"></td>
        <td id="Expensive-Rooms-Price"></td>
        <td id="Amount-of-Cheap-Room"></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is the js that I used to try to append data onto the table.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
      var database = firebase.database();
        database.ref('projectTable/hotelTable/Hilton/').orderByChild('hotel_name').once('value', function (snapshot) {

   if (snapshot.exists()) {
     var content = '';
     snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
     var val = data.val();
        content += '<tr>';
       content += '<td>' + val.hotel_name + '</td>';
       content += '<td>' + val.Location + '</td>';
       content += '<td>' + val.cheap_room_price + '</td>';
       content += '<td>' + val.max_amount_cheap_room + '</td>';
       content += '<td>' + val.expensive_room_price + '</td>';
       content += '<td>' + val.max_amount_expensive_room + '</td>';
       content += '</tr>';
           });
        $('#Marriott-hotel-list').append(content);
           }
         });

  </script>
```

I try to put the hotel name, Location, cheap_room_price, max_amount_cheap_room, expensive_room_price, max_amount_expensive_room, these values from the database onto the table.
But nothing shows on the web page and also I realize the table I made has no selectable feature. 
Can any expert point out my error and help me fix it in Javascript? Thank you and much appreciation!